# IndexedDB how to clear the DB when logging in?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I need to be able to clear and/or delete an IndexedDB when the the user comes back to my site. I want my DB to be fresh each time I login.

How would I clear or delete all objectStores in a DB when iniatlly loading a page?

Any thoughts on how to do this?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>IndexedDB test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
            var IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;
            var db;
            (function () {     
                var peopleData = [ 
                                 {"FILENAME":"/NewDesigMemo1026732160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | New Desig Memo","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CIC","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                                 {"FILENAME":"/NewDesigMemo1026732160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | New Desig Memo","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CISR","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                                 {"FILENAME":"/AttendanceOutOfStateMemo102673220160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | Attendance Out of State Memo","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CISR","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                                 {"FILENAME":"/Attend1026732160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | Attendance","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CSRM","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                                 {"FILENAME":"/NewMemo1026732160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | New Desig Memo","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CRM","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                                ];

                var peopleData2 = [ 
                                  {"FILENAME":"/Attend102673220160312.pdf","PRT_DATE":"3/14/2016","EC":"","DOC":"3/14/2016 | CSRM Attendance","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"","STATE":"","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"","DIST":null,"CNAME":""},
                                  {"FILENAME":"/RMagazine.aspx?I=r_spring_2016&P=1026732","PRT_DATE":"","EC":"","DOC":"R Magazine Spring 2016","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"","STATE":"","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"Spring 2016","DIST":null,"CNAME":""},
                                  {"FILENAME":"/Packet+Notification+CISR+CIC+20160309ALM.html","PRT_DATE":"3/9/2016","EC":"20160317LLM","DOC":"3/9/2016 | Packet Notification","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"","STATE":"","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"","DIST":null,"CNAME":"WTH"},
                                  {"FILENAME":"Eval20160317LLM1026732.pdf","PRT_DATE":"","EC":"20160317LLM","DOC":"Evaluation_Packet","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"ALM","STATE":"LA","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"","DIST":null,"CNAME":"WTH"},
                                  {"FILENAME":"Eval20160315LPR1026732.pdf","PRT_DATE":"","EC":"20160315LPR","DOC":"Evaluation_Packet","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"PR","STATE":"LA","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"","DIST":null,"CNAME":"IPR"}
                                 ]

                function initDb() {
                    var request = indexedDB.open("DocsDB", new Date().getUTCMilliseconds());
                    request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
                        db = request.result;     
                        // Only do the below if this is first visit to page...                                                       
                        if(window.performance) { 
                            if(performance.navigation.type  == 0 ) {
                                var store = getObjectStore(db);                   
                                // The db already exists so delete it and re-create it so we don't have stale records.
                                if(store != null) {
                                    store.clear();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    request.onerror = function (evt) {
                        console.log("IndexedDB error: " + evt.target.error.code);
                    };

                    request.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
                        var objectStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
                                 "docs", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });

                        objectStore.createIndex("docname", "DOC", { unique: false });
                        objectStore.createIndex("printdate", "PRT_DT", { unique: false });

                        for (i in peopleData) {
                            objectStore.add(peopleData[i]);
                        }
                    };
                }

                 function getObjectStore(db, mode) {
                     if(typeof db != 'undefined') {
                         var tx = db.transaction('docs', 'readwrite');
                         return tx.objectStore('docs');
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                 }

                function contentLoaded() {           
                    initDb();    
                    var btnPrint = document.getElementById("btnPrint");                

                    btnAdd.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        var transaction = db.transaction("docs", "readwrite");
                        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("docs");
                        for (i in peopleData2) {
                            var request = objectStore.add(peopleData[i]);
                            request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
                                // do something after the add succeeded
                            };
                        }

                    }, false);

                    btnPrint.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        var output = document.getElementById("printOutput");
                        output.textContent = "";

                        var transaction = db.transaction("docs", "readwrite");
                        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("docs");

                        var request = objectStore.openCursor();
                        request.onsuccess = function(evt) {  
                            var cursor = evt.target.result;  
                            if (cursor) {  
                                output.textContent += "id: " + cursor.key + " is " + cursor.value.FILENAME + " " + cursor.value.DOC;                            
                                cursor.continue();  
                            }  
                        };  
                    }, false);              
                }
                window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", contentLoaded, false); 
            })();   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Records" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print objectStore" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <output id="printOutput">
            </output>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does what I want. I got the idea from this post:
http://www.scriptscoop2.com/t/9f4135c0bf79/javascript-indexeddb-doesnt-reset-version-when-you-delete-a-database-on-chrome-bu.html
*[this site seems to have gone down but it was up on Tuesday]*
*Site seems to be back up as of 6/8/16*

Loads data from peopleData into the IndexedDB when it is loaded. It deletes the IndexedDB when entering and reloading but NOT when refreshing.

Click Print Button to show data in IndexedDB, click Add button to add records from peopleData2, then click Print Button again...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
            var db;
            window.refreshing = false;
            var peopleData = [ 
                             {"FILENAME":"/NewDesigMemo1026732160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | New Desig Memo","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CC","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                             {"FILENAME":"/NewDesigMemo1026732160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | New Desig Memo","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CSR","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                             {"FILENAME":"/AttendanceOutOfStateMemo102673220160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | Attendance Out of State Memo","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CSR","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                             {"FILENAME":"/Attend1026732160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | Attendance","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CSM","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                             {"FILENAME":"/NewMemo1026732160521.pdf","DOC":"5/23/2016 | New Desig Memo","PRT_DT":"5/23/2016","EC":"","STATE":"","DES":"CM","PRG_CODE":"","DIST":"","CNAME":""},
                            ];

            var peopleData2 = [ 
                              {"FILENAME":"/Attend102673220160312.pdf","PRT_DATE":"3/14/2016","EC":"","DOC":"3/14/2016 | CSRM Attendance","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"","STATE":"","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"","DIST":null,"CNAME":""},
                              {"FILENAME":"/RMagazine.aspx?I=r_spring_2016&P=1026732","PRT_DATE":"","EC":"","DOC":"R Magazine Spring 2016","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"","STATE":"","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"Spring 2016","DIST":null,"CNAME":""},
                              {"FILENAME":"/Packet+Notification+CSR+CC+20160309ALM.html","PRT_DATE":"3/9/2016","EC":"20160317LLM","DOC":"3/9/2016 | Packet Notification","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"","STATE":"","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"","DIST":null,"CNAME":"WTH"},
                              {"FILENAME":"Eval20160317LLM1026732.pdf","PRT_DATE":"","EC":"20160317LLM","DOC":"Evaluation_Packet","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"ALM","STATE":"LA","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"","DIST":null,"CNAME":"WTH"},
                              {"FILENAME":"Eval20160315LPR1026732.pdf","PRT_DATE":"","EC":"20160315LPR","DOC":"Evaluation_Packet","CRID":null,"PRG_CODE":"PR","STATE":"LA","DES":"","DATE_SENT":null,"PRG_DESC":null,"YEAR":null,"ISSUE":"","DIST":null,"CNAME":"IPR"}
                             ]
            function open() {
                var request = indexedDB.open("DocsDB");
                var upgraded = false;
                request.onupgradeneeded = function(evt) {
                    upgraded = true;
                    console.log("upgraded ok");
                    var dbnew = evt.target.result;

                    dbnew.onerror = function(event) {
                        console.log("IndexedDB error: " + evt.target.error.code);
                    };

                    var objectStore = dbnew.createObjectStore(
                             "docs", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });

                    objectStore.createIndex("docname", "DOC", { unique: false });
                    objectStore.createIndex("printdate", "PRT_DT", { unique: false });
                }
                request.onsuccess = function(evt) {
                    db = request.result;
                    if (!upgraded && !window.refreshing) {
                        throw "Not upgraded";
                    }
                    console.log("open ok");
                    request.result.onversionchange = function(e) {
                        if (e.newVersion === null) { // An attempt is made to delete the db
                            e.target.close(); // Manually close our connection to the db
                        }
                    };

                    if(typeof db != 'undefined' && !window.refreshing) {
                        var store = getObjectStore(db);                   
                        for (i in peopleData) {
                            store.add(peopleData[i]);
                            console.log("Added:"+peopleData[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                request.onerror = function() {
                    throw "Error in open";
                }
            }

             function getObjectStore(db, mode = 'readwrite') {
                 if(typeof db != 'undefined') {
                     var tx = db.transaction('docs', mode);
                     return tx.objectStore('docs');
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
             }

            function obliterate() {
                var request = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("DocsDB");
                request.onsuccess = function() {
                    console.log("delete ok");
                    open();
                }
                request.onerror = function(event) {
                    throw "Error in obliterate.";
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                if(window.performance) { 
                    if(performance.navigation.type  == 0 ) {
                        // The db already exists so delete it and re-create it so we don't have stale records.
                        obliterate(); 
                    } else {
                        window.refreshing = true;
                        open();
                    }
                }

                $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
                    var transaction = db.transaction("docs", "readwrite");
                    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("docs");
                    for (i in peopleData2) {
                        var request = objectStore.add(peopleData[i]);
                        request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
                            // do something after the add succeeded
                        };
                    }                    
                });

                $("#btnPrint").click(function () {                
                    var output = $("#printOutput");
                    output.html("");

                    var transaction = db.transaction("docs", "readwrite");
                    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("docs");

                    var request = objectStore.openCursor();
                    request.onsuccess = function(evt) {  
                        var cursor = evt.target.result;  
                        if (cursor) {  
                            output.html(output.html() + JSON.stringify(cursor.value) + '<br />');
                            cursor.continue();  
                        }  
                    };
                });                        

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- http://localhost:8040/idb_test3.html -->
        <div id="container">
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Records" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print objectStore" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <output id="printOutput">
            </output>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a listener function for the login event or load event or
   whatever
2. Increment a database version
3. Open a connection to indexedDB with the new version
4. Issue store delete or clear requests in the onupgradeneeded function

Edit: Here is some example pseudo-code in response to your comments.

```
<script type="application/javascript">

(function() { // BEGIN IIFE

// Get the current db version
var dbVersionString = localStorage.DB_VERSION || '0';
var dbVersion = parseInt(dbVersionString, 10);

// Increment the version and store it so next page load knows
dbVersion++;
localStorage.DB_VERSION = '' + dbVersion;

// Open a connection using the new version
var openRequest = indexedDB.open('mydb', dbVersion);
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = myOnUpgradeNeeded;
openRequest.onerror = console.error;

// Opening a new conn with higher version triggers this 
// upgrade callback
function myOnUpgradeNeeded(event) {
  // Get the connection variable
  var openRequest = event.target;
  var db = openRequest.result;

  // Reference the implicit versionchange transaction
  var tx = openRequest.transaction;

  // NOTE: this is assuming you only have 1 store. Otherwise you can 
  // loop over objectStoreNames, or you can just maintain your own 
  // list of known names and loop over that here.

  var docsStore;

  if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains('docs')) {
    // Create the store
    docsStore = db.createObjectStore('docs');
    docsStore.createIndex(...);
  } else {
    // Get and clear the existing store
    docsStore = tx.objectStore('docs');
    docsStore.clear();
  }

  // Put stuff in the store
  for(var i = 0, len = peopleData.length; i < len; i++) {
    docsStore.put(peopleData[i]);
  }
}

}()); // END IIFE

</script>
```

Comment: Could I use something like this for the "version": `new Date().getUTCMilliseconds()`

Comment: You have to obtain the objectStore in the `onupgradeneeded`, in order to clear/delete it, and at this point the db hasn't yet been opened so you can't get the objectStore. Also, if you pass the `evt.currentTarget.result` to get the objectStore, you get an error trying to use the transaction to get it. `var tx = db.transaction('docs', 'readwrite');return tx.objectStore('docs');`: `Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': A version change transaction is running.`

Comment: Any more help on this Josh?